# Wordpress ajax problem need wordpress expert?

Tags: ajax

i want to call a function using wordpress ajax and i have done a code for that also. but when i fire a ajax call it always retrun -1. i dont know what is the problem can any body help me to solve.

Here is my code

function.php

```
 function my_AJAX_processing_function(){
   //echo  $getLetter = $_GET['post_id'];
   print_r($_GET);
   exit;
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_title LIKE "'.$getLetter.'%" AND post_status = "publish" AND post_type="post"');
    while($row = $result)
    {
      echo '<a href="' . $row["guid"] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a><br>';
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_download_track_resources', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');
```

footer.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".downloadtrack").bind('click', function(){
            console.log(this.name);
            var siteurl = '<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>';
            alert(siteurl);
            var val = this.name;
            alert(val);
            var data = {action: 'download_track_resources', post_id: val};
            $.ajax({
                 url:siteurl+'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                 success:function(data){
                   alert(data);
                 }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Html code

```
<td height="25"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Download <?php the_title(); ?>" class="downloadtrack" name="<?php echo $post->ID;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite simple - you are not giving `admin-ajax` what it is expecting.

Please refer to the source code
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L17

```
if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die('-1');
```

So make sure you are giving it an action (which you are not). Then, a little [lower](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L33) there is:

```
if ( ! $id )
    die('-1');
```

So make sure you are logged in, and all the other prerequisites [AJAX in WordPress Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) require to function.

For more information check the [AJAX Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX).